# HttpMethod.releaseConnection() usage

Tags: java, httpclient

I am using HttpClient 3..0.1 with `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` and using the below code to fetch a page and also get the final redirected url of that page.

Multiple threads access this code in parallel. After running this code for some time, I start getting `ConnectionPoolTimeoutException` continously and then no pages are fetched further.

Is this related to my `connectionManagerParam` values which I should increase or I am doing something wrong in my code ?

```
GetMethod get = null;
    try {
        get = new GetMethod();
        get.setURI(uri);
        get.setFollowRedirects(false);
        int status = httpClient.executeMethod(null, get, new HttpState());

        String location = null;
        int retry = 2;
        if (get.getResponseHeader("location") != null) {
            location = get.getResponseHeader("location").getValue();
        }
        while (retry > 0 && ((int) (status / 100) != 2) && ((int) (status / 100) == 3) && location.length() > 0) {
            // To get the final redirected url.
            uri = URLUtil.createAbsoluteURIWithFix(location, null);
            get = new GetMethod();
            get.setURI(uri);
            get.setFollowRedirects(false);
            status = httpClient.executeMethod(null, get, new HttpState());
            if (get.getResponseHeader("location") != null) {
                location = get.getResponseHeader("location").getValue();
            }
            retry--;
        }

        if (status == 200) {
            uri = get.getURI();
            String html = URLUtil.getResponseBodyAsString(get, charsets);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        if (get != null) {
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
```

Exception stackTrace

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.doGetConnection(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.getConnectionWithTimeout(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:394)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:152)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
```

Do I need to call get.releaseConnection() after every execute method ? or the current coding is fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are not closing the first get and creating a new one that you affect to the same var .
And in loop yoy do the same thing.

You should keep only one instance in this code and clean it up at end in a global try/finally.

Comment: get.releaseConnection();   - doesn't close the first get  ?

Comment: The instance of get is overwritten  by the affectation within loop

Comment: ah...didn't see another  'new GetMethod()' inside a loop